# Law enforcement and communication in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars

I am attempting to write a few stories in the Star Wars setting. I am unclear about the way the laws and law enforcement work in that setting. Do planetary law enforcement agencies communicate with one another? How efficient are they? How do they track down lawbreakers from one planet to another?

The tale I have in mind involves the main character avoiding the law enforcement agencies, bounty hunters, and criminal elements but I want to make the story tense...keeping the protagonist just one step ahead of the law and the others after him and no more. Kind of like The Fugitive in space.

Comment: Any answer would depend on the time in question, so can you specify what timeframe your story would take place?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It also really depends on _where_; law enforcement is very different on a Hutt-controlled world than on one that's part of the Imperium.

Comment: One of the reasons bounty hunting is a successful industry is because they can operate outside of these systems. As @DavidW points out, a fugitive in one jurisdiction may be welcome in another. Same as in our world.

Comment: I dont think we can really answer the 'How' of your question since its very broad. If you were asking 'Could it happen' then I think the answer would be yes. But as far as I know the efficiency of interplanetary law enforcement isn't something explained in detail.

Comment: The holiday special has many of the elements you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the location. In places like the Outer Rim, Wild Space, or the Unknown Regions, where the Empire has little or no presence, it tends to be a lawless place, with bounty hunters being your interplanetary or interstellar enforcers, unless the Empire has taken interest in something (e.g. Rebel activity). In the Corporate Sector, Corporate Sector Authority (CSA) handles everything, and is better at communicating, but again, Imperial military and law enforcement are not present, though CSA does answer to the Imperial Security Bureau (ISB) (as shown in *Andor*). In the Mid and Inner Rims, the Empire has a much heavier presence. Between standard Imperial law enforcement, ISB, and the Imperial military, this has by far the best interplanetary and interstellar law enforcement.